# mediaelement.js not working properly in Quirks mode of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, mediaelement.js, quirks-mode

When we are view the video with mediaelement.js in Quirks mode of IE, it is not working properly. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Of course things don't work properly in quirks mode. Using Quirks mode means that you're deliberately switching off most of the browser features that have been invented since 2001. No modern JS libs are designed to work with quirks mode.

Or to be more explicit:

- Quirks mode is an **IE5**-emulation mode.
- Mediaelement.js is designed for **IE6** and higher.

You would be far better off thinking about how you can avoid using quirks mode than trying to force modern JS libs to work with it.

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but dropping quirks mode is probably the only way you're realistically going to get this library working (or most other modern libraries, for that matter).

The good news is that for most sites it's really not that difficult to fix things to use standards mode. There are some fairly basic changes you can make that will get you into standards mode but without having to actually change anything with your site layout.

I've given previous answers that went into detail about this, so I won't repeat myself here, but I suggest reading [the second half of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18316342/352765) for more info on how to move your site to standards mode.